# Google Analytics profile filters does not work

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

I have a website and I need to separate traffic to it into two profiles. 
I need to exclude data from curtain IP address from Profile A and include data from this IP to Profile B. 
I have created 2 profiles. Setup exclude filter by IP for profile A, setup Include filter for profile B. For some reason all data still goes to profile A. I use my own public IP address in filter definitions so I know for sure that I have visits for profile B. 
In order to test that data come to Profile A I track event via _trackEvent with unique name, like test123 and I see this event in Profile A.

What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: If I change filter to Country - everething work. I could easely separate traffic from me Country to another profile. So my guess something is wrong with IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem disappered when I reconfigured filtres with Advanced filters and put regex for IP address manually. It looks like something is wrong with standard filters UI.